# Installing Python 3.10+ on WSL2 Debian Distro

Tags: debian, wsl2, apt-get, python3

I'm fairly new to Linux distros.  I have Debian downloaded and running in my Windows 10 WSL2 environment.

I want to install a specific version of Python - 3.10 or latest 3.11 on it.  How can I do that?

I have tried:

```
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install python3 python3-pip
```

Which installs Python 3.5.3.

```
python3 --version
```

According to:

https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=python3

```
Package python3
stretch (oldoldstable) (python): interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 version)

3.5.3-1: amd64 arm64 armel armhf i386 mips mips64el mipsel ppc64el s390x
buster (oldstable) (python): interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 version)

3.7.3-1: amd64 arm64 armel armhf i386 mips mips64el mipsel ppc64el s390x
bullseye (stable) (python): interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 version)

3.9.2-3: amd64 arm64 armel armhf i386 mips64el mipsel ppc64el s390x
bookworm (testing) (python): interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 version)

3.10.6-1: amd64 arm64 armel armhf i386 mips64el mipsel ppc64el s390x
sid (unstable) (python): interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 version)

3.10.6-3: alpha amd64 arm64 armel armhf hppa i386 ia64 m68k mips64el mipsel ppc64 ppc64el riscv64 s390x sparc64 x32

3.10.6-2 [debports]: sh4
```

Looking at my Debian distro - this is `stretch`.

`cat /etc/os-release`

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
VERSION_CODENAME=stretch
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Is it possible to do this through install purely through `apt-get`?  Or do you need to download the sources and compile then install?

https://cloudcone.com/docs/article/how-to-install-python-3-10-on-debian-11/

In the meantime, I have spotted an update for Debian in the Windows Store which should give me the `bullseye` version - once I setup a new environment.

**UPDATE**

I have updated my distro from the Windows Store.  I've had to issue the following commands:

```
wsl --unregister Debian
wsl --install -d Debian
```

Now I have:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

I have had to install python again from scratch:

```
sudo apt install python3 python3-pip
```

This installs:

Python 3.9.2

Comment: It looks like you are on the right track. Because you are on Deb 9 (Stretch) you get the one made available in the package 3.5.x. If you want to get it natively using apt install - you will then upgrade your Linux to bookworm at least. Debian is quite famous for being very slow in accepting newer version of anything. So if you want the latest of things - you either need to compile yourself, or use a different distro.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm fairly new to Linux distros.

No worries!  We all were at some point.  There's some important background here to understand what's going on.

> `sudo apt install python3 python3-pip`

Linux distributions provide the convenience of "package management" (`apt` in this case, under Debian) and repositories of software that those distributions have tested and "approved" (might be too strong a word) for the distribution.

Python, especially, is a *critical* piece of a Linux distribution  -- So much functionality in a Linux system is often provided via Python.  For that reason, it's *not* advised to change the Python version that *comes* with the system, although there are methods for using a separate Python version above-and-beyond the system release:

- [Use Docker](https://askubuntu.com/a/1424207/1165986) to run a different version of Python
- [Pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#getting-pyenv)
- Install from source with a separate `--prefix` or using `sudo make altinstall` (see [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/890959/1165986).

Note that some options that are available on Ubuntu won't work on Debian:

- To my knowledge, there's no reliable PPA for Python on Debian.  PPA's are Personal Package Archives.  On Ubuntu, the [Deadsnakes PPA](https://askubuntu.com/a/682875/1165986) appears to be trusted, but it is not tested on Debian.
- Ubuntu 22.04 has recently added 3.11 to the repositories (not as the default) for installation with `sudo apt install python3.11`, but from my package search on Debian (also under WSL for both), that is not the case.

#### Additional background

Some additional background on how Linux distributions and their repositories work that is relevant here.  There are, in general, two types of distributions:

##### *Cadence/Stable release distributions*

These releases typically update on a regular basis.  E.g. Ubuntu, Debian, Redhat, OpenSUSE Leap, and many others.

For instance, Ubuntu releases every 6 months, in April and October.  However, only the "April release in even years" (e.g. 22.04) is considered a "long-term support" (LTS) release which gets 5 years of support and updates.  The other 3 releases in-between are short-term, and only get 9 months of support.

These releases focus on *stability* more than the latest-and-greatest packages.  *Especially* for Python, which is a dependency for many other features and packages in *any* Linux distribution, it's important to make sure that updates don't break other functionality (or at least reduce the risk).

Debian Stretch was pretty old, and [past end of life](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianReleases).  Bullseye is the latest stable, and Bookworm is the latest testing.

As you can see, the latest *stable* includes 3.9.  If you want to upgrade Debian to a Testing release (Bookworm), then it would have 3.11 (from the [package list](https://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bookworm/main/)), but in general I'd use one of the other methods listed above.

---

### *"Rolling release" distributions*

The other type of distribution is the "Rolling release" style.  Examples include Arch, Artix, openSUSE Tumbleweed, Gentoo, and many others.

These distributions focus on updating packages "constantly".  Once a new Python version is tested, it will get updated in the repository, and can be installed by the normal package-management update system.  There may still be a slight delay (days to weeks, depending on the package/maintainers/testing/issues/etc.), but you don't have to wait for the next "major" release of the distribution.

Comment: Ha - I was experimenting in a specific version to see what it would take to get Python setup in that particular disto.  I was using Debian (finally upgraded to bullseye) that would have Python installed.  I did resort to using docker image `python:3.11.0-bullseye` - but I am trying to gain a better understanding in this area.

Comment: @Andez Sure - Any other questions?  If it's something quick, I can attempt to answer in the comments or edit my answer.  If it's going to take a bit to explain, it might warrant a new question.